# Angular Project To Maven War File On Tomcat

Tags: java, html, angular, maven, war

My company wants to start a new Angular project, and I am told to deploy the Angular Project as a War File, so it can be uploaded in the artifactory we have and it can easily be deployed to Tomcat 8.

However I have not much knowledge about War Projects. In my view it is too much overhead, why would you use a Java Format for a Web Client?

Just to understand, the backend Java Code is seperated, so in the end my App  will only contain JavaScript, HTML and CSS.

So I have created an empty Maven Project with IntelliJ, created a new folder  in which I created a new Angular Project with the CLI.

And this is my pom.xml inside the Angular project folder, so far:

```
    <project xmlns = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test.maventest</groupId>
  <artifactId>wartest</artifactId>


  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>wartest</name>
  <packaging>war</packaging>


  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <finalName>maventest</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          <webResources>
            <resource>
              <directory>dist</directory>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

As far as I understood, I need to copy my HTML and so on in the

> target/WEB-INF/classes

folder, am I right? but my Maven file will not do that. It will create a new folder inside target, so it looks like:

> target/maventest

In there I have a META-INF and a WEB-INF folder.

Now how can I accomplish this, it must be easy in my view..

Answer (score 0):

> As far as I understood, I need to copy my HTML and so on in the
>
> target/WEB-INF/classes
>
> folder, am I right?

No, you are not. The target folder will be generate automatically after maven process finish. The folder is also deleted if you run the command

```
mvn clean
```

This web project's folder structure is created by maven:

[image]

Hope this helps.